# Both the Row Number and Field Value Appear in Cell Values Pulled from DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I filled a DataTable (`dt`) with values from several text and double fields using various data sources (Excel, Access, etc.).  I then populated a DataGridView from `dt`, and the text, integer, and real (double) columns are visible in the DataGridView and don't have any issues.

However, in one area of my code I am fetching age values (column 6) of specific cells using the code

```
Dim myage As Integer = dt.rows(i)(j)
```

The value of age in row 0 is 19, so when using `myage = dt.rows(0)(6)` on most occasions the age appears as `19`.  However, in another area of my application (using the same `dt` and code to fetch age values) the age appears as `0 19`, where 0 is the row number of `dt`.  If I get the row 1 value for age using dt.rows(1)(6) it shows as `1 24`.

Why is the dt yielding only a numeric value in one area of my application, and yielding the row and the age in another area of my application?

I am not sure if use of `.row` is the issue, and I already tried `dt.rows(1).Field(Of Integer)(6)` and it doesn't prevent the row number from appearing.

Since I need to pull cell values from `dt` in numerous places in my app, how can I avoid this dilemma?

Comment: What you describe is simply not possible. The `Field(Of Integer)` method will return an `Integer` and "0 19" and "1 24" are not `Integers`. That means that it must be something that you are doing with the data rather than the data itself. From your description, it sounds you haven't actually debugged the code, so you shouldn't even have posted a question here yet. If you don't know how to use the VS debugger, stop what you're doing and learn now. You then need to ALWAYS debug your code before posting and provide the information you get from the debugger.

Comment: I know that no exception is being thrown, which proves that your columns do not contain the data you're implying. Calling `Field(Of Integer)` would throw an exception if the field did not contain an `Integer` so no exception proves that it does. It will also return an `Integer` value so it can't possibly return the values you are reporting. That proves that either you're not providing us with accurate information or else the problem is being created by your code after you get the data out of the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding datatable column change your datatype to integer for ex :  `dt.Columns.Add("Age", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))` then try it will support.

Comment: @wrstks, none of what you said makes any sense. `DBNull` is absolutely NOT `Nothing`. The very reason that `DBNull` exists is that value types could not have no value when ADO.NET was created (they can now via nullable value types). You should absolutely set the `DataType` of each column to the type of the data it will contain. That will not stop any column containing `DBNull`. It won't help with your problem though, based on what you have posted elsewhere, but it is still what you should be doing.

Comment: That's a bad way to set the data type. It's more verbose than necessary and it's also error-prone, because you're using a `String` to represent the data type. Only do it that way if you must get the data type as a `String` from some external source. If you're hard-coding the type, always use a data type, e.g. `dt.Columns.Add("Age", GetType(Integer))`. In this case, you're using the `GetType` keyword (it turns blue) and not a member of a class. Because you're specifying a data type, the compiler will prevent you from misspelling it.

Comment: Nope, still nonsensical. I understand what you're saying about data types, etc, but none of that justifies your specifying `Object` as the data type for your columns. If a column is supposed to store `Integers` then it's `DataType` should be `Integer`, regardless of whether it is nullable or not. Also, a `DataRow` has it's own method for the purpose of checking, e.g. `xobject(i, j) = If(dt.Rows(i).IsNull(j), CObj(Nothing), dt.Rows(i)(j))`.